# Try to upload video to cloud server but cannot get file system path from cameral roll

Tags: ios, file, system, filepath

I tried to upload video from iphone cameral roll to own cloud server in my code.

I can obtain the URL from  ALAssetsLibrary which looks like "assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=CB9F174C-CC5A-4979-8BBE-1174FCC4F63B&ext=mov". This is not the file system path. It couldn't be used with Owncloud library for iOS which requires the file system path.

https://github.com/owncloud/ios-library

I have following questions.

1) The file system path for the video cannot be obtained through ALAssets. Is there any other way to get the absolute file system path?

2) If the file system path cannot be obtained for the video, shall i get video data through ALAssetRepresentation and try to stream the data to the server? But i don't have a library that can stream data to owncloud server yet. Is there any recommendation on any library that can do this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"The file system path for the video cannot be obtained through ALAssets. Is there any other way to get the absolute file system path?"

No. You can't access the asset on the filesystem.

"If the file system path cannot be obtained for the video, shall i get video data through ALAssetRepresentation and try to stream the data to the server? But i don't have a library that can stream data to owncloud server yet. Is there any recommendation on any library that can do this work?"

You can use the asset representation to get the bytes and write those to a location in the `NSCachesDirectory` or `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. At that point you have an accessible filesystem URL for the data which you can hand off to Owncloud.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In such case, copying the video file into a temp location is inevitable. Through it would make the upload time longer, there is probably no other choice to make it work.